# How do I unset (undo) unix set -C in zsh?

Tags: command-line, unix, zsh

This works as expected

```
$ echo "foo" > foo
$ cat foo                # foo
$ echo "updated" > foo
$ cat foo                # updated
```

---

From `man set`

```
-C      If  set, bash does not overwrite an existing file with the
        >, >&, and <> redirection operators.  This may be overridden
        when creating output files by using the redirection operator
        >| instead of >.
```

Ok, so let's `set -C`

```
$ set -C
$ echo "bar" > bar
$ cat bar                # bar
$ echo "updated" > bar
file exists: bar
```

This is all well and good, but now it's time to turn off `set -C`.

**How do i disable `set -C` after it's been turned on?**

---

I've tried:

```
$ unset -C
zsh: bad option: -C
```

Comment: BTW, zsh is NOT bash.....

Answer (score 18):

Blah. It's as simple as

```
$ set +C
```

Of course I find the answer immediately after posting the question.

The man pages don't really mention the difference between `+` and `-`.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are using the *Z shell*, but quote the *bash* man page.

Just to clarify, the `set -C` and `set +C` commands work also in zsh, but more easily to memorize are IMHO *shell options*:

```
setopt no_clobber
```

This is equivalent to `set -C`. And, to disable this option, there is indeed a `unsetopt` builtin:

```
unsetopt no_clobber
```

All options are listed with `man zshoptions`. Options are kind of symmetric, so `setopt no_clobber` is equivalent to `unsetopt clobber`. That's why, in the man page the *CLOBBER* option is explained:

> **CLOBBER (+C, ksh: +C)**
>
> Allows `>` redirection to truncate existing files, and `>>` to create files.  Otherwise `>!` or `>|` must be
>                 used to truncate a file, and `>>!` or `>>|` to create a file.

A related option (IMHO very handy) is

> **HIST_ALLOW_CLOBBER**
>
> Add `|` to output redirections in the history.  This allows history references to clobber  files  even  when  CLOBBER is unset.

Demo:

```
zsh$ setopt no_clobber hist_allowclobber
zsh$ echo foo > baz
zsh$ echo bar > baz
zsh: file exists: baz
zsh$ [Arrow UP]
zsh$ echo bar >| baz
zsh$
```

And as a last remark, options are case-insensitive and underscores are ignored, hence `NOCLOBBER`, `NO_clobber`, `noclobber` are treated the same way.